# Can't import modules in Python interactive mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, anaconda, command-prompt

I wrote a batch file to run a python script in interactive mode, because it's easier to debug:

> Run.bat

```
python -i CmdTest.py
```

This file is supposed to run the following python script (in the same folder)

> CmdTest.py

```
import pandas as pd
input("end")
```

However, I can't import the module

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

I know that pandas works fine when running the script normally. Is there a way to fix this problem?

By the way, I have installed python via Anaconda

Comment: It looks like the version of python you have doesn't know where the `pandas` module is. What's the output of `which python`?

Comment: `which python` returns 



`'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

On the other hand, I tried `python --version` it says `Python 3.6.5`

Comment: What is the result of `python -c "import pandas"`?

Comment: This is what happens when I try your code, EPo: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'`